# PHP Session not working on the server

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I'm making a super simple ticket tracking system with PHP and sessions and I'm having some trouble, I have the following pages:

- admin.php (the page where you can create, edit and delete tickets)
- login.php (the page where you login)
- logout.php (not a page, just the logout code)
- edit.php
- add.php
- delete.php

When you go to the admin.php if the session isn't set, it takes you to login.php.

In login.php if the session is set, it takes you to admin.php.

The username and password is stored in the login.php file as plaintext because secutiry isn't the main concern here and it's just a username and a password.

This is the code in admin.php

```
<?php
    include "includes/header.php";
    include "includes/config.php";
    include "includes/db.php";

    session_start();
    $admin = isset($_SESSION['myAdmin']) ? $_SESSION['myAdmin'] : false;

    if(!$admin){
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    $db = connect();

    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM tickets');
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

This is the code in login.php

```
<?php
    include "includes/header.php";

    session_start();
    $admin = isset($_SESSION['myAdmin']) ? $_SESSION['myAdmin'] : false;

    if(isset($_SESSION['myAdmin'])){
        header('Location: admin.php');
    }

    $user = 'myUsername';
    $pass = 'myPassword';

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : false;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : false;

    if($username && $password){
        if($user == $username && $pass == $password){
            $_SESSION['myAdmin'] = true;
            header('Location: admin.php');
        }
    }
?>
```

It's working wonders on localhost, but I can't get it to work on my server. Both are running PHP 7.0 and all the database configs are fine.

This is what happens:

When I log in and put the right username and password it just reloads login.php, now if I go to admin.php it shows the admin page as if the session was created.

Even if I delete all browsing data or try it in incognito mode. It still does the same. Is there something I'm not seeing? Thanks in advance.

By the way, this is the logout code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['myAdmin']);
    header('Location: login.php');
?>
```

When I open admin.php I can see the logout link and when I click it takes me login.php but I can still go to admin.php if I type it in the browser.

What's throwing me off is that I don't know how to debug, because when the variable is null or undefined or false/true, echo won't show anything.

EDIT: Ok so, after each `header` line I've added this `exit();` and the page shows blank after login or in admin by default. And now I can see the problem clear.

The header (redirect) is not working. When using ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); the error says:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by and it points the line with the `header`. I suspect the session_start() may have something to do with it.

Comment: For debugging you should use `var_dump()`, it will print any type of variable to the screen.

Comment: It's generally good practice to halt execution of your code after submitting a `header()` redirect, either by using `exit()` afterwards, or by wrapping it in a conditional so that nothing else executes after it. It may be that on the server, the redirect code is executing as you expect, but it's being negated because the rest of your script is still running and creating output.

Comment: I tried with exit() and die() and I'm getting 500 internal server error

Comment: @ishegg I'll try that and update...

Comment: @NickCoons ok so I tried it again and it seems that exit() works and I also used var dump, and effectively, the session is created but the redirect doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: By the way, I turned on the option to see errors and I'm getting headers already sent, by I don't have any echo so I don't know what's causing this? And why it works on localhost? but not on the server

Comment: Can you update the code in your question with the changes you've made so we can see it in its current form?

Comment: Done @NickCoons

Comment: I'm not seeing it. It doesn't appear that you've actually added `exit()` after your various `header()` lines.

Comment: Oh I didn't change the code in the post, I tried it and it didn't work so I didn't put it, but I commented it on the EDIT below

Answer (score 1):

session_start() and header('Location: login.php') should come before header.php

```
    session_start();

    if(!$_SESSION['myAdmin']){
        header('Location: login.php');
    }

    include "includes/header.php";
```

Anytime you call header() it must be invoked before any other output on the page. Otherwise you will get the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: Doesn't work, says the same 
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: That means that you're calling header('Location: login.php'); to late on the page. header('Location: login.php'); has to come before echoing anything or any html.

Comment: session_start() has to be the first thing on the page then header('Location: login.php');

Comment: First change the first 7 lines of admin.php to 

<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myAdmin'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
}

then close all private browsers, then open a new private browser and go to admin.php, it should redirect you to login.php

Comment: tried it and now I don't get anything, just a blank page

Comment: What is the url?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PHP redirection, try:

```
`<?php echo '<script>window.location.replace("url")</script>'?>`
```

Comment: PHP is compiled in the server and then sent to the client (the browser). The problem is that you put that header('Location: login.php'); after HTML code is sent to the browser. Use Javascript instead.Try   if(!$_SESSION['myAdmin']){
echo '<script>window.location.replace("login.php")</script>';
    }